# How to use operators inside select in xsl tag?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML file (some service documentation) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apis>
    <api min="2.2" max="3.0">
        <resource name="products">
            <description>products from 2.2 to 3.0</description>
        </resource>
        <resource name="brands">
            <description>brands from 2.2 to 3.0</description>
        </resource>
    </api>
    <api min="1.0" max="2.2">
        <resource name="products">
            <description>products from 1.0 to 2.2</description>
        </resource>
    </api>
    <api min="2.1" max="2.2">
        <resource name="brands">
            <description>brands from 2.1 to 2.2</description>
        </resource>
    </api>
    <api min="1.0" max="2.1">
        <resource name="brands">
            <description>brands from 1.0 to 2.1</description>
        </resource>
    </api>
</apis>
```

And when I want to take both resource description in API version for example 2.1 using groovy and XmlParser I can do this by:

```
def rawXml = new XmlParser().parse ( 'file.xml' )
rawXml.api.findAll {
         node -> node.@min <= '2.1' && node.@max > '2.1' 
}.resource.description
```

Now I want to do this but into HTML file using XSLT. I try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="apis">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Resource name</th>
                        <th>Resource description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="api[@min<='2.1'] and api[@max>'2.1']">
                        <xsl:for-each select="resource">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't work. I've noticed that problem is with operators '<=', '>' and 'and'. I changed

```
'api[@min<='2.1'] and api[@max>'2.1']'
```

to

```
'api[@min&lt;='2.1']'
```

or to

```
api[@max&gt;'2.1']
```

and it works. But

```
'api[@min&lt;='2.1'] and api[@max&gt;'2.1']'
```

doesn't. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_operators.asp tells that it should for xpath but xsl select have problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both of the boolean expressions in one predicate (`[]`) if you want to apply both at the same time to one `api` element :

```
<xsl:for-each select="api[@min &lt;= '2.1' and @max &gt; '2.1']">
```

The above should correctly loop through `api` elements that has both `min` attribute value less than or equal to `2.1` and `max` attribute value greater than `2.1`.

Comment: Might also want to drop the quotes around `2.1` since presumably it's a numerical, not lexical, comparison that's desired here.

Comment: In XPath 1.0 the `<` and `>` operators always do numeric comparison (both operands converted to numeric) - but in a sense that makes it even more important to make it unambiguously a numeric comparison, because otherwise you have a compatibility problem when moving to 2.0.